# Mask NumPy array and extract values where condition is met

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, extract, mask

How can I mask two NumPy arrays properly? I want find `pe` values that are not equal to `255`, for example. I also want my desired output array be the same size as`pd` and `pe`, i.e., `(7, 7)` and filled with `0's`.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

```py
import numpy as np

pd = np.random.randint(254,256, size=(7,7))
pe = np.random.randint(0,7, size=(7,7))
```

**Desired output**

```
[[6 6 0 0 6 6 1]
 [2 6 1 1 5 6 3]
 [3 4 6 6 3 5 6]
 [3 5 0 3 2 0 0]
 [0 3 6 1 3 6 1]
 [6 3 4 1 0 3 1]
 [6 0 4 2 2 6 4]]
```

Many thanks

Comment: So for each index in the output array, you'd like `pe[index] if pd[index] != 255 else 0`, right?

Comment: `pe * (pd == 255)`, IIUC. Assuming you meant *that are not equal to 255 **in pd***

Comment: Which is slightly faster than `np.where(pd == 255, 0, pe)` which I was going to propose. Kudos! :)

Comment: Hi Dominik. Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Note that we optimized significantly `np.where` in the very last version (1.23) of Numpy so `np.where(pd == 255, 0, pe)` may now be faster than `pe * (pd == 255)` or at least close to that.

Comment: @JérômeRichard - [Nice](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/21130), less benchmarking when considering `np.where`

Comment: I am working with small size datasets, thus computational speeds are not a problem. However, this is very good to know, Jérôme. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical indexing seems the simplest of all options.

```
import numpy as np

pd = np.random.randint(254,256, size=(7,7))
pe = np.random.randint(0,7, size=(7,7))

pe[pd == 255] = 0

[[3 6 0 2 0 0 0]
 [0 3 4 5 2 0 5]
 [0 0 6 0 1 0 5]
 [0 3 0 4 0 6 0]
 [2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [2 0 4 0 0 0 5]
 [0 0 3 0 2 4 0]]
```

Based on your data size, you may try other options:

```
pe = np.where(pd == 255, 0, pe)
# OR
pe = pe * (pd == 255)
```

but I guess indexing is still simple and fast.

Comment: Many thanks for a clear reply, AboAmmar!